# Jewish Renewal and patrilineality

Tags: heterodox, judaism

Reform Judaism and Reconstructionist Judaism recognize as Jews by birth children of a Jewish father and a non-Jewish mother who were raised exclusively in Judaism. What does Jewish Renewal say about this?

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit difficult to say because Jewish Renewal isn't organized as one coherent group, so decisions are typically left to individual congregations and Rabbis as the [Half-Jewish Network states](https://halfjewishnetwork.wordpress.com/who-is-a-jew):

> The Jewish Renewal movement does not have an official position on the Jewish status of children of intermarriage. Decisions on Jewish status are left up to the individual rabbis. The Renewal community has a large number of interfaith families. We have received only one complaint about discrimination against patrilineals within a Jewish Renewal community.

Having said that, if you take a look at some Jewish Renewal-affiliated synagogues such as the [Or Shalom synagogue, their Patrillineal descent policy on their website states](https://www.orshalom.ca/patrilineal-descent-or-shalom-policy/):

> After reviewing the Vaad’s report, and after considerable G-d-wrestling, Or Shalom’s Board concluded that we should adopt the following policy decisions:
>
> 1. Or Shalom affirms that people of patrilineal Jewish descent have a claim on Jewish identity. That means we at Or Shalom will not question their own sense of belonging and attachment to the Jewish people and Jewish life.

At the same time however, they say (this is what they mean by full participation):

> 2. For full participation as a Jew at Or Shalom, people of patrilineal Jewish descent will require mikvah*, and additionally for men, brith mila** or hatafat dam***. There will be no further eligibility requirements for individuals of patrilineal Jewish descent with their own sense of belonging and attachment to the Jewish people and Jewish life. The practical implications for those of patrilineal descent would be the following:

> a) Or Shalom continues the practice that we have had throughout our history. As a community we are open to all that are interested in sharing with us and we will continue to welcome everyone.
> b) While everyone is most welcome to share in our community, it is important that someone who acts and speaks for the community in religious context be someone who is accepted in that role by the whole community.

> **There are two particular roles where this acceptance is important.** One is **serving the community as shaliah tsibbur, which means, in effect, being the one chosen from among the community by the community to stand before us and lead us all in davvening.** The **other role is being called to an aliya** (including Bar or Bat Mitzvah). This means saying the brachot for a Torah reading on behalf of the entire community gathered together at that time.

Hence, generally speaking (even on the Half-Jewish Network website), Jewish Renewal for almost all of the affiliated synagogues recognizes patrillineal descent. As long as one feels as a part of the Jewish people, they are not questions. And keep in mind that Or Shalom is a synagogue officially affiliated with [Aleph](https://aleph.org), the umbrella organization of Jewish Renewal communities, so they do have some authority within this realm. But do understand that a lot of them might require the standard Jewish protocols to be performed in order to be able to conduct all of the actions fully in the synagogue, even though they might see you as a Jew by merely having patrillineal descent.

All in all, it is best that you consult Rabbis and synagogues in the Jewish Renewal movement on a case by case basis in order to find out what they think about patrillineal descent and belonging in Judaism, but for almost all of them, it seems that they recognize patrillineal descent and are accepting as long as one feels a part of the Jewish people. In here, I just wanted to demonstrate what it would look like for one synagogue for example.